# What's wrong with this RC Phase Shift Oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, simulation, multisim

I am trying to design a phase shift oscillator, using a CE Amplifier. I have a Vc of approximately 12V, gain of approximately 250 I aim for an oscillation frequency of  60 Hz.

But whenever I start the simulation, no oscillations take place. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the circuit?
When I convert into hardware it works perfectly, but not in simulation. I am using NI Multisim circuit design suite 14.[image: NI Multisim]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third phase shift stage (that is closest to Q1's base) is "ruined" by the biasing resistor R2. R2 is in parallel with R8 and it greatly reduces the value of R8. Instead, remove R2 and make R5 much bigger so that the appropriate base DC voltage is produced (circa 1 volt).

A test you can do is to open the feedback loop and inject an AC signal into C1 (from the left) and do a bode plot to see what output voltage you get at the collector. At the point you have output and input in-phase there should be a gain greater than 1.

Comment: I tried it , it indicates at 1Khz gain starts increasing above 1 but dips below after 10 ghz. How could i calculate the output voltage

Comment: That tells you the problem. You have a gain less than 1 at 60 Hz hence the circuit won't oscillate. This is because you need to get rid of R2 and increase R5 to something like 330 kohm. Try the sim again.

Comment: Wow , that works . Can you explain why it works? There is a huge voltage drop across the R5, transistor won't turn on right? But hardware with same circuit above works well why?

Comment: There is meant to be about 11 volts DC across R5 to set the base at about 1 volt. This in turn sets the emitter at about 0.3 volts DC.

Comment: But when i remove the source connect it as a positive feedback it's not working

Comment: Operating at the desired voltage i.e. 1 v at the bias point. Still it wasn't working. Just a steep increase in the output voltage

Comment: I tried a simulation of the circuit with almost all values shown except - R2 removed; R5 = 180K; Q1 changed to a pair of 2N3904's connected as a Darlington pair. It oscillates at ~55Hz.

Comment: Changing C1, C2 and C3 to be 47nF brings the simulation frequency much closer to 60Hz.

Comment: @MichaelKaras well done. I'm just in the process of simulating myself.

Comment: @BalaSubramanian maybe you need to let the simulation run for about 1 second to see if the oscillation begins. Sinewave oscillators are not immediate starters.

Comment: If you need more gain, increase the emitter cap beyond the value of 100µF (for example 200 or 500µ)